# NetworkManager on Fedora 15 can't find frequently used wireless network

Tags: linux, fedora, networking

NetworkManager has refused to find the wireless network I always connect to. It sees other wireless networks except the one which I need. In recent past occasions, I've had to delete the wireless network and restart my system, and it worked.

But those steps have not been helpful today. Has anyone experienced this before?

I'm running Fedora 15 on a Dell Inspiron 1525.

Comment: Does `iwlist wlan0 scan` list the network?

Comment: that's happened to me before. in my case, the distribution I was using (Xandros) edited /etc/network/interfaces to include all of my networks, and NetworkManager didn't like that. but i've found that if you have *any* other network managers installed (like wicd) these interfere with NetworkManager too. for what it's worth, the day I stopped using NetworkManager (uninstalled it) and simply edited /etc/network/interfaces to autoconfigure my networks, I became a *lot* happier. unix networking's been around for a few decades; in fact, the first networks were unix. if it ain't broke don't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Is it that NetworkManager refuses to find or does not find?

Either way, I would suggest you please check if the wireless network is available for other devices, meaning the wireless network is not itself down?
Please also check the client side's wireless adapter status using the `lspci` command. Run `service wpa_supplicant restart`  and see if that helps too.

Comment: It refuses to find. Other computers and devices around me are connected to the wireless network. Is there a status to look out for in the `lspci` command? I've also run `service wpa_supplicant restart` but nothing changed.

Comment: `lspci` would give you a output, check whether there is any mention or references of the wireless card. Does `ifconfig wlan0` show anything? what is the output of `ifconfig -a` anyway?